# VMWare workstation 10 no 3d acceleration after many tries

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have a ASUS Zenbook UX31A and recently I've felt the need for VS2013 so I installed VMWare Workstation 10 because of it's Unity feature.Things have gone crazy since I made so many attempts in order to get this 3d acceleration enabled.It still shows me "3d acceleration is not supported".

Things I tried:

- `mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE"`
- Installing missing libraries like `libtxc-dxtn-s2tc-bin`
- Installing Intel drivers
- driconf -> forced s3tc

But I still can't get 3d acceleration, despite many tries. I just don't understand what goes wrong.

`glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 VGA`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Zenbook Prime UX31A [1043:1517]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:0153] (rev 09)
```

`glxinfo | grep -i render`

```
direct rendering: Yes
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp,
```

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: I would need to know if you have installed vmware tools in your guest OS

Comment: It's installed.VMWare workstation shows me two messages when I run my VM that 3d acceleration isn't supported.

Comment: "direct rendering: Yes" says that you have acceleration. Where does it says that you doesn't?

Comment: @Braiam VMWare throws error messages that 3d acceleration is not supported

Comment: @bain No it's not. This guy has no support of 3d acceleration in his drivers while mine say they can.

Comment: If you have followed the instructions for enabling 3D in VMWare and it isn't working then this is an issue with VMWare. VMWare installs its own proprietary 3D drivers and is responsible for routing those GPU commands to the host GPU. Perhaps you could try VirtualBox?

Comment: @bain anyway Unity feature and VS2013 work without 3d acceleration, so I'm fine. I will eventually open a support ticket in VMWare.